# Why does propel fail to set this ENUM field to "Y"?

Tags: php, orm, mariadb, propel2

I'm scratching my head over this. I have the following table:

```
<table name="activity" idMethod="native" phpName="Activity">
  <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" size="13" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
  <column name="created" phpName="Created" type="TIMESTAMP" required="true" defaultExpr="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"/>
  <column name="modified" phpName="Modified" type="TIMESTAMP" required="true" defaultExpr="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"/>
  <column name="provider_id" phpName="ProviderId" type="INTEGER" size="13" required="true"/>
  <column name="name" phpName="Name" type="VARCHAR" size="100" required="true"/>
  <column name="description" phpName="Description" type="LONGVARCHAR"/>
  <column name="grade_min" phpName="GradeMin" type="INTEGER" size="2" required="true" defaultValue="0"/>
  <column name="grade_max" phpName="GradeMax" type="INTEGER" size="2" required="true" defaultValue="12"/>
  <column name="duration" phpName="Duration" type="INTEGER" size="3" required="true" defaultValue="60"/>
  <column name="image" phpName="Image" type="VARCHAR" size="255" required="true" defaultValue=""/>
  <column name="webpage" phpName="Webpage" type="VARCHAR" size="255" required="true" defaultValue=""/>
  <column name="approved" phpName="Approved" type="CHAR" sqlType="enum('Y','N')" required="true" defaultValue="N"/>
  <foreign-key foreignTable="provider" name="activity_provider" onUpdate="CASCADE">
    <reference local="provider_id" foreign="id"/>
  </foreign-key>
  <unique name="provider_name">
    <unique-column name="provider_id"/>
    <unique-column name="name"/>
  </unique>
  <vendor type="mysql">
    <parameter name="Engine" value="InnoDB"/>
  </vendor>
</table>
```

And I execute the following PHP:

```
$approved = $activity->getApproved();
if($approved == "N"){
  $activity->setApproved("Y"); // verified this line is executing
} else {
  $activity->setApproved("N");
}

echo $activity->getApproved(); // this outputs "Y"
$activity->save(); // produces line in the query log
die($activity->getApproved()); // this outputs "N"
```

A line is produced in the query log from the `save()` method:

```
[2018-02-26T17:00:09.038703-08:00] default.INFO: UPDATE activity SET approved='N' WHERE activity.id=6 [] []
```

When the `approved` field is set to `Y`, the same query runs and is successful (the field is toggled to `N`). Any ideas what might be going on here? Does Propel2 hate ENUM? Any suggestions to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Try with `<column name="approved" phpName="Approved" type="ENUM" required="true" valueSet="Y, N" defaultValue="N"/>`. My guess is that `CHAR` is messing things up and it defaults to `N` as specified.

Comment: @ishegg thanks for the `valueSet` idea. Even though my issue wasn't related to `enum`, that is useful knowledge. Apparently propel's `ENUM` columns are backed by `integer` columns in the database, so it doesn't work in my case (dealing with a populated reversed database, so I don't want to switch the `enum` field to `integer`), but it would appear that `valueSet` is working with `CHAR`. Or at the very least `propel model:build` is not complaining.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found the cause of the issue I was having. I had a `preSave` hook on the `Activity` model that set approved to `"N"` on save. The intention was that if the activity was changed it would lose its approved status, but because saving happens after `setApproved("Y")`, the hook fires and sets it to `"N"`. I fixed it by detecting whether the `Approved` column was being modified and only setting the `Approved` column to `"N"` if it was not being modified.